# monitor air quality

Tags: sensor

I would like to build a device to monitor few chemicals (CO, NH3, H2S) and particulate (PM2.5 and 10) in the air. I have been looking online for related sensors and I found that the MQ-X series (CO=MQ7, NH3=MQ136, H2S=MQ136) and SDS011 for PM might be suitable for my case.

In the tutorial (https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/configure-and-read-out-the-raspberry-pi-gas-sensor-mq-x/) MQ-2 sensor only is being used. Other two components are Analog-to digital convertor (ADC) (8 ports) and Logic-level convertor (LLC) (to cut down the voltage 5 to 3.3).

Would it be possible to build a multi-sensors device with a single a pi? Would I need the same ADC and LLC mentioned in the tutorial only? Which version of pi would you recommend? Sorry for the many questions but I am quite new with raspberry pi and hardware in general. Thank you

Comment: Hi @diegus, Welcome and nice to meet you. A couple of days ago I played with MQ9 to detect CO quantity. You might like to read my answer and CHAT RECORD of the following question:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/how-can-rpi3b-detect-mq9-gas-sensors-carbon-monoxide-leakage-without-using-ad

Comment: Hi @tlfong01 thank you for the info. Sure I'll read it

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.