# How can Rpi4B connect and read the the EC4-2000-CO sensor?

Tags: sensor, pi-4

How is Raspberry pi 4 connected with EC4-2000-CO sensor? Can someone please let me know about the hardware and software setup of the same?

Comment: Hello @Trinity, Welcome and nice to meet you. Let me see. (1) You need some sort of OP AMP based biasing circuit to get an analog output of the CO sensor, say of the range DC -2.5V to  +2.5V. Then you need an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter), Eg SPI ADS1256 24 bit resolution, set up to convert the analog to digital 24 bit or three bytes data.  Rpi4B can use SPI protocol to set up, read, and convert the ADC signal. You might like skim the references below: / to continue, ...

Comment: References: 
(1) "EC4-2000-CO Carbon Monoxide Electrochemical Sensor - SGX SensorTech":
https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2014/07/EC4-2000-CO1.pdf,

(2) "Electrochemical Sensors Application Note 2 Design of Electronics for Electrochemical Gas Sensors - SGX SensorTech":
https://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2014/08/A1A-EC_SENSORS_AN2-Design-of-Electronics-for-EC-Sensors-V4.pdf,

(3) "Dual Electrochemical Gas Sensor with Temperature Compensation":
https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/reference-designs/CN0396.pdf, / to continue, ...

Comment: (4) "How can Rpi4B python read negative result values of the SPI ADS1256 24 bit ADC?":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108746/how-can-rpi4b-python-read-negative-result-values-of-the-spi-ads1256-24-bit-adc/108844#108844, (5) "How Can Rpi3B+ Detect MQ9 Gas Sensor's Carbon Monoxide Leakage, Without Using ADC?":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/how-can-rpi3b-detect-mq9-gas-sensors-carbon-monoxide-leakage-without-using-ad. Cheers.